# Converting strings to date in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, t-sql, sql-server-2017

I am using SQL Server 2017. I am trying to handle strings from a free format field and either convert them to a date in the format of "dd/mm/yyyy" or if they are not in this format then simply display the text verbatim.

I need this in a VIEW so can not use SET LANGUAGE. Sounds simple using `Convert` and `IsDate` but does not seem to work.

So for the snippet of code below (remember this will be in a view), I want to read the text and if the string converts to a date (ie. is in the format `dd/mm/yyyy` then run the convert to a date as I need it in date format for Excel to pick up (via Connect SQL Server database)), and if it does not convert to a date then display the text as it is.

```
create table dateTest1 
( 
    idx int, 
    dateStringTest varchar(15) 
); 
  
insert into dateTest1 (idx, dateStringTest) 
values (1, '13/01/2021'), (2, 'no'); 
 
select 
    case 
        when isdate(convert(datetime, dateStringTest, 103)) = 1 
            then convert(datetime, dateStringTest, 103)
        else dateStringTest 
    end as dtres
from 
    dateTest1 
--where idx = 1
```

Error:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 15
> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

This error happens for idx = 2. Idx = 1 works ok.

Any assistance with this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: A column cant be both a datetime type and varchar at the same time. If it must be a datetime column, you might need 2 queries. 1 for the valid datetimes and 1 for non-datetimes

Comment: SQL Server 2017. Still no luck. I have the data all coming to excel without any errors. But the columns in EXCEL are showing the dates as strings. They should be showing as Date. Even if i change the format of the column in Excel its not changing the format of the string

Comment: Use `TRY_CONVERT` - it will return a `NULL` if the value passed in (the `varchar`) cannot be converted to a date - instead of throwing an error

Answer (score 1):

You need to *cast* your resulting date to a `varchar`. A `case expression` can only return a single data type and the order-of-precedence means it is still trying to convert the varchar values to `datetime`

```
select 
       case when isdate( dateStringTest) = 1 
       then Cast(convert(datetime, dateStringTest, 103) as varchar(10))
       else dateStringTest 
       end as dtres
from dateTest1
```

You can compact into a single statement (the same order of precedence applies)

```
select IsNull(Cast(Convert(datetime,Try_Cast(dateStringTest as date),103) as varchar(10)),dateStringTest)
from datetest1
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. As above unfortunately TRY_CONVERT is not recognised. I am using SQL SERVER 2017.

Comment: @gfsadmin - I'm not sure what you mean, `try_convert` is supported in SQL Server 2017. [See this working Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7bddc6fc7ae8890470bb6c42947ede2b)

Comment: try_convert requires 2012 compatibility and our db was 2008 compatibility. In anycase this did not address the issue. Trying to handle strings in the format of dd/mm/yyyy but when the script reads a date such as 13/06/2021 it fails. I want this as a date format not a text format, Any assistance would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Based on the syntax you are using, I assume you are using SQL Server.  You should add the appropriate tag to your question.

The only way to do that in one column is to leave it as text.

Your use of `ISDATE()` is incorrect.  If dateStringTest is not a valid date, `CONVERT()` on SQL Server will throw an error like:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

That's why you get an error for idx=2

You say you "need it in date format for Excel to pick up".  How Excel interprets it will probably depend on your locale settings.  Assuming `mm/dd/yyyy` is valid in your locale, Excel probably already sees it as a date.  But I assume that's not happening, so `mm/dd/yyyy` is not valid for your locale.  For me, if I have this table in SQL...

```sql
create table dateTest1 (
    id int identity(1,1) not null,
    dateStringTest varchar(20)
)

insert dateTest1
values
  ('2020-01-01')
, ('2020-21-01')
, ('2020-01-21')
, ('1/1/2020')
, ('1/21/2020')
, ('21/1/2020')
, ('21/01/2020')
, ('other stuff')
```

...and query it from Excel, adding columns with the functions `DATEVALUE`, `DAY`, `WEEKDAY`, and `YEAR`, I get...

| id | dateStringTest | DATEVALUE | DAY | WEEKDAY | YEAR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 | 43831 | 1 | 4 | 2020 |
| 2 | 2020-21-01 | #VALUE! | #VALUE! | #VALUE! | #VALUE! |
| 3 | 2020-01-21 | 43851 | 21 | 3 | 2020 |
| 4 | 1/1/2020 | 43831 | 1 | 4 | 2020 |
| 5 | 1/21/2020 | 43851 | 21 | 3 | 2020 |
| 6 | 21/1/2020 | #VALUE! | #VALUE! | #VALUE! | #VALUE! |
| 7 | 21/01/2020 | #VALUE! | #VALUE! | #VALUE! | #VALUE! |
| 8 | other stuff | #VALUE! | #VALUE! | #VALUE! | #VALUE! |

That seems to indicate that Excel is recognizing some of the values as dates.

What you need to do is try to convert the value to `datetime`, then if it fails report the original value.  In both cases, output a string.

You should review the documentation for [`CONVERT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Try this:

```sql
select dateStringTest
, coalesce(cast(try_convert(datetime, dateStringTest, 103) as varchar(20)), dateStringTest) as dtres1
, coalesce(convert(varchar(20), try_convert(datetime, dateStringTest, 103), 103), dateStringTest) as dtres2
, coalesce(convert(varchar(20), try_convert(datetime, dateStringTest, 103), 101), dateStringTest) as dtres3
from dateTest1
```

**UPDATE**

If you are considering only values matching the pattern `dd/mm/yyyy` as dates (so 17/01/2021 is a date and 17/1/2021 is not), this brute force method will work with SQL Server 2008 (compatibility level 100):

(Notice I updated my input, also, above.)

```
;
with a as (
    select id
    , dateStringTest
    , SUBSTRING(dateStringTest, 7, 4) + '-' + SUBSTRING(dateStringTest, 4, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(dateStringTest, 1, 2) as converteDate
    from dateTest1
)

select id
, cast(convert(datetime, dateStringTest, 103) as varchar(20)) as dtres
from a
where isdate(converteDate) = 1

union
select id
, dateStringTest as dtres
from a
where isdate(converteDate) = 0
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. Unfortunately TRY_CONVERT is not recognised. I am using SQL SERVER 2017.

Comment: `TRY_CONVERT` works in SQL Server 2012 and higher, if you are using a compatibility level of 110 or higher.  Check your compatibility level:  `select name
, compatibility_level
from sys.databases`

Comment: And here's a chart showing which compatibility levels are available in which versions of SQL Server:  https://glennsqlperformance.com/2020/08/20/database-compatibility-levels-in-sql-server/

Comment: Thanks i changed it to 2012 compatibility and try_convert was recognised. This did not fix the issue though.  when i insert other dates that are compatible with "mm/dd/yyyy" (ie. the first part of the date is between 1 - 12) then the statement seems to work. But in Australia our format is dd/mm/yyyy and dates where the dd is greater than 12 then it fails.

I cant use SET LANGUAGE in a VIEW.

Not sure how to tell the VIEW that the string is in a format of dd/mm/yyyy not mm/dd/yyyy.

Thanks

Comment: It looks like SQL Server is using your locale and Excel is not.  There may be some value for you to read the documentation for `CONVERT()` and spending time experimenting with it.  See my revised answer.